# Azure ML LibraryExecutionError

Tags: c#, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I get the following error when trying to retrieve the data from Azure Machine Learning

```
Error: LibraryExecutionError
Target: Score Model (AFx Library)
Message: table: The data set being scored must contain all features used during training, missing feature(s): 'NA'.
```

If I include NA within the values that get sent to Azure I get the following message

```
Parsing of input vector failed. Verify the input vector has the correct number of columns and data types
```

Has anyone got any idea's on how to fix this issue?

James

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is suggesting that the model you produced from the training experiment uses a column named "NA", and this column doesn't existing in your scoring dataset.

Comment: I've checked the training experiment and I can't find any column named 'NA'. Do you have any idea where that might be?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of detail to go off, but have you had NA values in that factor before? It sounds like you have a categorical factor and are entering a value for which it has no match and your model does not have the "allow unknown categories" checkbox checked.